# Computed p_value is not equal to reported p_values in survreg

Tags: r, survival

I am fitting a model using survreg and then I got the following result:

```
    Scale= 1.165371 

Loglik(model)= -4117.3   Loglik(intercept only)= -4162.5
    Chisq= 90.53 on 10 degrees of freedom, p= 4.2e-15 
n= 1000
```

Now I want to get the p (4.2e-15) and used the following code:

```
signif(1 - pchisq(summary(srFit)$chi,  summary(srFit)$df), 2)
```

and the result is 3.9e-14. I think I'm calculating p correctly but not sure why the values is different.

Comment: That's a bit odd...but reproducing this agrees with survreg's results: try `1 - pchisq(90.53, df = 10)`

Comment: Thanks, it gives me 4.218847e-15 which is very close, but why did you choose df =10?

Comment: the output from servreg indicates 10 degrees of freedom (i.e. 10 regression parameters, other than the intercept).

Comment: True, but when I get srFit$df,   it gives me  12, I don't know why?

Comment: Ah, probably because there are also two baseline parameters in most survreg parameterizations (only 1 for exponential distribution). So there's a total of 12 parameters in your model, but given your baseline distribution (probably weibull?), you will always fit at least 2. That is why the output says 10 degrees of freedom: its comparing no regression parameters (but 2 baseline) with all 10 regression parameters (+2 baseline)